# 'background-image' se sobrepone al contenido de la página

Tags: html, jquery, css

En mi página tengo varias tablas y `div`'s, casi todo el contenido de mi página tiene la propiedad `position: fixed;` menos la última tabla, esta al ser muy grande y querer recorrer todos los registros automaticamente uso la función `animate({ scrollTop: },)` de `jquery` para que vaya bajando el scroll, anterirormente la tabla que se recorría se ocultaba detrás del contenido que estaba fijo y eso es lo que busco exactamente, pero al usar la propiedad 'background-image' para agregar una imagen de fondo a una celta de la tabla, esta imagen no se oculta sino que se muestra sobre el contenido fijo, pero todo lo demás que contiene la tabla sí se oculta. ¿Hay alguna porpiedad que me permita ocultar también la imagen de la celda o de qué forma puedo lograr este efecto?

Comment: Creo que seria mas facil ayudarte si nos suples algo de codigo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día M.Gar, comentas que estás usando fixed, recuerda que cuando ocupas un elemento de tipo fixed lo ideal es utilizar un posicionamiento o la manera en que se visualizarán, es decir, cual irá primero y cuál irá después. A tus objetos que tienen la propiedad `fixed` agregales `z-index: valor`

p.e.

```
div.myID{
    position: fixed,
    z-index: 2
};
```

Y el background quedaría de manera normal.

Podrías intentarlo por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias Eliseo, me faltaba el `z-index` no lo había puesto